# How to make a transition automatically in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs, div1 and div2. Only one div will be show. Each 3000miliseconds one div will be `hide();` and the other will be `show();`.

Example:

div1 - `show();` 
div2 - `hide();`

.... 3000miliseconds...

div1 - `hide();`
div2 - `show();`

I tried make this.. But without success.

```js
$(function() {
  var div1 = $('.div1');
  var div2 = $('.div2');

  $(document).ready(function() {
    div1.show();
    div2.hide();
    setInterval(3000).ready(function() {
      div1.hide();
      div2.show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="div1" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <a>
                        Content of DIV1
                    </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <a>
                        Content of DIV1
                    </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <a>
                       Content of DIV1
                    </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <a>
                         Content of DIV1
                    </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>

<aside class="div2" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <a>
                         Content of DIV2
                    </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <a>
                        Content of DIV2
                    </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <a>
                         Content of DIV2
                    </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <a>
                         Content of DIV2
                    </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/pzjrQA1.jpg

Comment: "I tried make this.. But without success."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** the view in the `setInterval()`.

```js
$(function() {
  var div1 = $('.div1');
  var div2 = $('.div2');

  $(document).ready(function() {
    div1.show();
    div2.hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      div1.toggle();
      div2.toggle();
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="div1" style="border: 1px solid black">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <a>
            Content of DIV1
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <a>
            Content of DIV1
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <a>
            Content of DIV1
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <a>
            Content of DIV1
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</aside>
<aside class="div2" style="border: 1px solid black">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <a>
            Content of DIV2
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <a>
            Content of DIV2
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <a>
            Content of DIV2
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <a>
            Content of DIV2
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thank so much @Rejith , are small details that make the difference. One more thing, how can I put an opacity in the transition?